# TeamCity Build for release/* so that it picks up latest release version

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to create teamcity build pipeline  for release/* branch.I created VCS root with hardcoded value for release e.g. Default branch:  refs/heads/release/1.0.0 but this is hard-coded and for each release I need to manually change the release number. Is there any way to set Default branch and Branch specification: which checks for latest release/* branch and run the build?

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the branch to be build in branch specification

```
 buildAndTestConfig.triggers {
        vcs {
            branchFilter = """
            +:*
            """.trimIndent()
            groupCheckinsByCommitter = true
            triggerRules = "+:release/base/*"
        }
    }
```

but a better method would be to refs/heads/release as the base branch and for each change in build number the build counter to create a folder and copy the results using the buildcounter.So you would have a base branch,when first time project is build,a new folder will be created with the build number,use that folder to copy the results .

Comment: I've set refs/heads/release as Default Branch but got error Cannot find revision of the default branch 'refs/heads/release' of vcs root 'jetbrains.gi